# Surface Integral and why "r" from (polar) change of variables is missing from the integral?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, surface-integrals, change-of-variable

> I'm ask to find the surface area of the cylinder $x^2+y^2=2x$ limited
>   by the cone $z=\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}$ and the plane $z=0$ and . I know that
>   the cylinder's center is at $(1,0)$
>
> $x^2+y^2=2x$ can be rewritten as $(x-1)^2+y^2=1$: a circle with centre
>   $(1,0)$ and radius $1$.
>
> First parametrise by setting $x-1=\cos \theta$, $y=\sin \theta$
>
> This gives $z=\sqrt{2x}=\sqrt{2(\cos \theta+1)}$.
>
> We can now imagine the cylinder being unwrapped, so that the area is:
>
> $$\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{2(\cos \theta+1)} d\theta$$

Basically from my understanding of the above:the surface area of the cylinder limited by the cone is

$$ \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\sqrt{2(\cos\theta+1)}drd\theta$$

I was told that when doing integration in polar coordinates,

> $$dx dy=r dr d\theta$$ .

Is the "$r$ " in the integral: $$\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{2(\cos \theta+1)} d\theta$$ missing or equal to one?

I expected the surface area of the cylinder limited by the cone to be instead 
$$ \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\sqrt{2(\cos\theta+1)}rdrd\theta$$

and not :$$\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{2(\cos \theta+1)} d\theta$$

What's going on with "$ r$ " from the jacobian?

This is a followup question on :[Area cylinder limited by cone](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2021933/area-cylinder-limited-by-cone/2021971#2021971).

Comment: Your double integral is the *volume*, not the *area* of the surface.

Comment: Are we integrating with respect to the two form$ dzd\theta$ or the twoform $drd\theta$? Because I think z is r the radius or z=r

Comment: I would say we are integrating $z\,ds$ where $ds$ is the length element on the circle. With the given parametrization of the unit circle we have $ds=d\theta$.

Comment: So the surface area is equal to the one form integral where it’s just the area under the curve z which is a function of one variable theta?

Comment: So all one-form integrals under absolute valuel are in some way calculating some surface area?

Comment: Make sure that you understand what "we can now imagine the cylinder being unwrapped" means. If you cut the cylinder along the vertical line then you can unwrap it and make flat without any deformation (thus, no need for "Jacobian"). The flat area can be described by a single (one-dimensional) integral.

Comment: @A.Γ. Just to be clear, we're finding the surface area of the closed solid cylinder $' x^2+y^2\leq 2x$ that lies inside the cone?

Comment: We are finding the surface area of that part of the cylinder $x^2+y^2=2x$ that lies between the cone and $xy$-plane, only side area - no bottom, no lock.

Comment: Is the surface area of the cylinder $ x^2+y^2=1 $  limited by the cone $  z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$  the same thing as the surface area of the cone limited by the cylinder? What exactly does "limited" mean? How can I tell what's limiting what?